# Jquery - google chrome problem, incorrect function call !

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have a code with jquery and it works in All browsers (even ie6 !!!) but it does not work in chrome .. it calls incorrect functions in wrong time so it displys wrong stuff ...

have tryed to fixed it with 100 different ways, almost rewrote all the code, but the same

Maybe anyone could spot a problem that could fix it ...

Link here !!! Added everything that is useful - http://jsfiddle.net/EQywA/2/  - works in every browser in chrome no !!! I thing is understandable whats wrong now !!

Ideas anyone ???? :)

Comment: Could you please give us some information on what this does and what it does wrong specifically in google-chrome?

Comment: Just so  `$('.order a').attr('onclick','return false');`, onclick isn't an attribute, you should write : `$('.order a').click(function() { return false; });` instead

Comment: You can continue this one: http://jsfiddle.net/EQywA/1/

Comment: Added everything that is useful - http://jsfiddle.net/EQywA/2/  - works in every browser in chrome no !!! I thing is understandable whats wrong now !! @mplungjan @Arnaud F. @DalexL

Answer (score 2):

I am seeing a syntax error in Chrome.  I don't know how well you know chrome, but if you just hit Cntrl-Shift-j you will get the javascript console which shows the error.

```
});
</script>
```

I deleted: });

and no longer get the error.

EDIT:
instead of using nth-child which isn't working, try:
var index = $this.parent().prevAll().length

change

```
if($(this).parent().is('.product form .variant_box_option:nth-child(1)'))
```

to

```
if($this.parent().prevAll().length == 0)
```

Comment: Maybe i have posted with errors in real website there are no such error !!! Added everything that is useful - http://jsfiddle.net/EQywA/2/  - works in every browser in chrome no !!! I thing is understandable whats wrong now !!

Comment: Open the same link in ff(or ie or etc.) and in chrome and you will see, text box should change and get green only when all select items are selected. But in chrome it changes after second one from 4 :S

Comment: the nth child code isn't working in chrome.  you might want to try something else.